# {"index": 0,"code": 11000,"keyPattern": {"Name": 1}, "keyValue": { "Name": null }} error on adding second product to database

Tags: node.js, database, express, mongoose

On trying to add a product to my database using the following method,

```
//ADD PRODUCT
router.post("/addproduct", verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  const newProduct = new Product(req.body);

  try {
    console.log("req for pdt add");
    const savedProduct = await newProduct.save();
    console.log("pdt added successfully");
    res.status(200).json(savedProduct);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Mongoose is throwing this error when adding the second product. The first product is successful always but cannot make a second post request and also put request to update the product details is not working, but the delete request works perfectly fine

```
{
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "keyPattern": {
        "Name": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
        "Name": null
    }
}
```

Given below is my product schema

const { default: mongoose } = require("mongoose");

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    desc: { type: String, required: true },
    img: { type: String, required: true },
    category: { type: Array, required: true },
    size: { type: String },
    color: { type: String },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

Comment: It is probably caused by the `unique` index specified on the `title` property. Are you sure that you are inserting objects with different titles?

Comment: Yes, I was inserting products with different titles, but I removed unique, that was the solution that I could find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your MongoDB field "name" have Properties UNIQUE at the field "Indexes". And you have to drop that property or you never can create the same name value even if it a empty value.

I used to have the same error, and this is my resolution for the issue:

[image: See this image to explain what I'm saying.]

Answer (score 0):

This error comes as a result of a model waiting to receive data that should actually come from the body of the request, but because it cannot read it because you did not add the middleware app.use(express.json()). Therefore, it creates the index but without all the data.

Answer (score 0):

I get exactly similar error, actually the solution to your problem is to do unique false. My problem is a bit more complicated, I use idNumber as unique but sometimes I need to use null value, in these cases it shouldn't check for uniqueness and unfortunately sparse:true doesn't solve my problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1PuN.png)